# Combine salesorders to one invoice from server action on stock.picking

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, server-action

How can i adjust the following code so dat odoo will combine the sales orders from the same customer to one invoice like wen you do it from the tree view in sales.orders.

```
for record in records:
    if record.picking_type_code == 'outgoing':
        sale_order = record.sale_id
        if sale_order:
            sale_order.action_invoice_create()
            invoices = sale_order.invoice_ids
            if invoices:
                last_invoice = invoices.sorted(key=lambda i: i.id, reverse=True)[0]
                
                last_invoice.action_invoice_open()
                error_message='FACTUUR OKE: ('+ str(last_invoice.number) +')'
                record.write({'x_error': error_message})
                
            else:
                record.write({'x_error': 'No invoices found for the sale order'})
        else:
            record.write({'x_error': 'No sale order associated with the record'})
```

The above code is a server action on the model stock.picking. It works fine but makes individual invoices of each delivery / sale order. If possible i would also like to call a custom serveraction with id 1183 to run on last_invoice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to gather all orders first and call `action_invoice_create` on them. Odoo will group them in the process. It is very similar to using the list functionality.

For example:

```py
orders = self.env["sale.order"]
for picking in records:
    if picking.picking_type_code == "outgoing":
        orders |= picking.sale_id
orders.action_invoice_create()

for order in orders:
    # do you error stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sale_ids = []
for picking in records:
    if picking.sale_id:
        sale_ids.append(picking.sale_id.id)

if sale_ids:
    # Create Invoices
    invoices = env['sale.order'].browse(sale_ids).action_invoice_create()

    # Confirm Invoices
    if invoices:
        env['account.invoice'].browse(invoices).action_invoice_open()

        # Update x_error in stock.picking
        for picking in records:
            if picking.sale_id and picking.sale_id.id in sale_ids:
                last_invoice = picking.sale_id.invoice_ids.sorted(key=lambda i: i.id, reverse=True)[0]
                error_message='FACTUUR OKE: ('+ str(last_invoice.number) +')'
                record.write({'x_error': error_message})
```